# Writing API requests with completion blocks using Swift generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, completionhandler, type-alias

I am experimenting with generics in Swift and I am attempting to push it to its limits.

In my application I have a super simple API wrapper around Alamofire. The structure is like so:

```
API -> Request -> Alamofire request
```

Here is some generic code that I threw into a playground to test some concepts. Here is what I have so far:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var cheese: String { get }
    init()
}

class Something: SomeProtocol {
    required init() { }

    var cheese: String {
        return "wiz"
    }
}

class API {

    class func performRequest<T: SomeProtocol>(completion: (T?, NSError) -> Void) {

        // This code is irrelevant, just satisfying the completion param
        let test = T()
        let error = NSError(domain: "Pizza", code: 1, userInfo: nil)

        completion(test, error)
    }

}

func test() {
    API.performRequest<Something> { item, error in

    }
}
```

Calling the function gives the error:

```
"Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function"
```

****** UPDATE ******

As per the answer below, removing the typical <> generic type specifier and instead adding the expected type to the completion params solves the issue. Just a quick example:

```
func test() {
    API.performRequest { (item: Something?, error) in

    }
}
```

Additionally, I have discovered that making the API wrapper class a generic class solves the issue like so:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var pizza: String { get }
}

class SomeObject: SomeProtocol {
    var pizza: String { return "pie" }
}

class API<T: SomeProtocol> {
    class func performRequest(completion: (T?, NSError?) -> Void) {

    }
}

func test() {
    API<SomeObject>.performRequest { item, error in
        // Do something with item, which has a type of SomeObject
    }
}
```

Either way, the end goal is accomplished. We have a single generic method that will perform a set of tasks and return, via completion closure, the object based on the type passed in with each use.

Comment: I believe the compiler does not know which type to apply to the function. Try specifying the parameter type in your closures.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using generics? From what I understand, iOS typically infers type based on scanning params. It appears that completion closures do not properly support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way generics work is they allow a function to use unspecialized variables inside of its implementation. One can add functionality to these variables by specifying that the variables must conform to a given protocol (this is done within the declaration). The result is a function that can be used as a template for many types. However, when the function is called in the code itself, the compiler must be able to specialize and apply types to the generics.

In your code above, try replacing

```
func test() {
    API.performRequest<Something> { item, error in

    }
}
```

with

```
func test() {
    API.performRequest { (item: Something?, error) in

    }
}
```

this lets the compiler know which type it must apply to the function without explicitly specifying. The error message you received should now make more sense.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, I misunderstood your first statement. Your code example makes complete sense. Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did using alamofire and alamofire object mapper:
Step 1: Create modal classes that conforms to Mappable protocols.

```
class StoreListingModal: Mappable {
var store: [StoreModal]?
var status: String?
required init?(_ map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    store <- map["result"]
    status <- map["status"]
}
}
```

Step 2: Create a fetch request using the generic types:

```
func getDataFromNetwork<T:Mappable>(urlString: String, completion: (T?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).responseObject { (response: Response<T, NSError>) in
        guard response.result.isSuccess else{
            print("Error while fetching: \(response.result.error)")
            completion(nil, response.result.error)
            return
        }
        if let responseObject = response.result.value{
            print(responseObject)
            completion(responseObject, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: Now all you need is to call this fetch function. This can be done like this:

```
self.getDataFromNetwork("your url string") { (userResponse:StoreListingModal?, error) in

    }
```

You will not only get your response object but it will also be mapped to your modal class.